# Keras: make specific weights in a dense layer untrainable

Tags: neural-network, keras, mask

I need to design a multilayer perceptron with two hidden layers and one output layer. The weight matrix between the second hidden layer and the output layer contains some non-trainable weights which are fixed to 0 based on theory. Is there a way to do this in Keras?

Comment: You can freeze the weights of a layer: `layer.trainable = False`. Please do some research before asking and look at the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers).

Comment: I in fact researched about layer.trainable = False, but that is not what I want. My understanding is that it freezes the entire layer. I want to only freezes specific weights in one layer, while other weights remain free.